# How is politico.com inserting a hyperlink into copied text?

Tags: javascript

If you visit [this article](http://www.politico.com/news/stories/0509/22574.html) on politico.com, highlight some of the article text, then paste that text elsewhere, it will contain a link that says "Read more at: ...".  How is this done?

Update: This is the JS used, but hard to follow: http://tcr.tynt.com/javascripts/Tracer.js

Comment: ...tried to follow directions and got the text I cut and pasted, not what you're describing. Might need better instructions.

Comment: It doesn't at "Read more at: ..." in Firefox 3.0.10.

Comment: Odd, it does it for me every time.

Comment: Works for me, as long as I copy the entire article text.

Comment: Worked that way for me - super cool stuff - though there is an even cooler feature! When I paste the link into firefox, the text i had selected originally was highlighted in bright yellow. +1 for a great find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that it's just like any copy to clipboard script, but you insert the "Read more at :.." text in the front, and you listen for the oncopy event.

So instead of just doing:
window.clipboardData.setData("Text", textToCopy);

you'd do

window.clipboardData.setData("Text", "Read more at: mysite.com , " + textToCopy);

More here:

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread53662.html

Comment: This isn't what they do - that would fail in all but the most insecure browser set-ups. What that script actually does is append the extra text in a hidden div to your selection as you do it. Then when you copy it includes the extra info. Very clever!

Answer (score 1):

On politico.com, the code that does what you say there is in tracer.js.